# How to extend an existing dynamic object in c# with some more dynamic properties

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I want to add new properties with values in a existing object.

I've tried the following code:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(element.ToString());
                            var t = new { data };
    
                            var valorLInhasacntigas = CreateExpandoFromObject(t);
    
                            IDictionary<string, object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
    
                            var a = propName;
                            obj[a] = valores[i].Valor;
    
                            obj = obj;
                            neeList.Add(valorLInhasacntigas);
```

But i doesnt work.

**Example of what i want:**

*

> Input:{ id: 1, name: Banana }, {color: yellow, type: fruit}

- 

> ***Expected Output*: {id: 1, name: Banana, color: yellow, type: fruit}**